# How to change button on click on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a on off single button which will change the background image of button on click. At initial the button should be red showing off and when clicked it should change colour to green and show on.

Comment: What have you tried ? Add your code

Comment: You can use Toggle Button or switch .then you can handle event like that.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
follow this official[toggle button documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton#java)

Comment: If you don't want to use toggle button, then you can achieve that by using a boolean flag set to true first then onClick of button change accordingly and set the desired color to your button.

Answer (score 1):

Create Boolean flag to check weather button is On or Off.

change button background color on button click event also change Boolean flag value

```
boolean isRed = false;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(isRed){
            isRed=false;
            button.setBackgroundColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
        }else{
            isRed=true;
            button.setBackgroundColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a xml named colors.xml in res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

In drawable folder, create a xml file my_btn_toggle.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/red"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/green"  />
</selector>
```

and in xml section define your toggle button:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:background="@drawable/my_btn_toggle"/>
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked actually I want code when the button is on the firebase database value should be 1 and when off it should be 0.

Comment: Can you marked the answer true or upvote me if it has helped you then @PrasadJadhav